# Wordpress - you are using and outdated browser

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I actually have problem with wordpress page. My page on chrome and firefox load fine, but when I'm trying to load it on IE I have a communicate:

"You are using and outdated browser" - but version of installed IE is the newest one.

I see when I'm loading page on my server it load normally. Problem just occurs outside server.

Comment: This is not Wordpress default behaviour, so it must be related to some plugin you're using, or your theme. Search for the error message in your Wordpress files to see where it comes from.

Comment: @vard I have template monster and I was searching help on their live chat. I just heard that it isnt template error, bug will be also with default wordpress theme. Live demo on templatemonster works fine. Maybe problem is about WAMP configuration, what do you think?

Comment: Well WP doesn't show any alert about browser compatibility by default, at least not on front-end. If you have access to source it would be interesting to see how they do the browser check - for example if they use `get_browser`, which rely on browscap.ini to works, it would fail as wamp possibly doesn't bring it (it's not bundled with php).

Comment: @vard in file header.php I found 
`<?php /* The HTML5 Shim is required for older browsers, mainly older versions IE */ ?>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <div id="ie7-alert" style="width: 100%; text-align:center;">
   <img src="http://tmbhtest.com/images/ie7.jpg" alt="Upgrade IE 8" width="640" height="344" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
</div>
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->`

but i'm sure I have IE 11.

Comment: The last line you quoted target IE >= 9. Is there anything after it?

Comment: @vard yes, it is.

`<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
  <script src="<?php echo PARENT_URL; ?>/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.sf-menu').mobileMenu({defaultText: <?php echo '"' . apply_filters( 'cherry_text_translate', html_entity_decode( of_get_option('mobile_menu_label') ), 'mobile_menu_label' ) . '"'; ?>});
   });
  </script>
 <!--<![endif]-->`

Comment: I don't thinks it's relevant - this script seems to do some action on the menu so it shouldn't display any error like that. I think this message is triggered somewhere else. Did you tried to search for the error message in the whole `wp-content` folder? It would be easier that way to track down where the message is triggered.

Comment: @vard I solved this problem. My browser default load ie 7 on this page. I added meta tag to header.php 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`
Thanks for help ;)